# Magento 1 : Category page not shown in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, backend, category-view

On the Magento-Dashboard under **Catalog > Manage Categories** is shown only the left colom with the already created categories.

But I can't create new one or modify the existing ones. Take a look at the Picture and you will understand my problem

Below, the image of the page with the error: **Catalog > Manage Categories**

[image]

Comment: Did you delete any files?, or check for possible conflict in your browser's console log

Answer (score 0):

Please check your browser consol for error

May be you have installed  some theme or extension and that extension created some dropdown or multiselect attribute

Now may be you are not using that extension(you have disabled that extension) so magento not able to find model for dropdown and because of that you are facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Working on Elisa Kits' Magento installation, I found the reason:

There was an extension (Gelo / Qrcode) overwriting the block for the tabs on the category edit panel. This extension was deactivated in the backend. When calling the categories backend page, I found out that the extension's overwriting class was still used in the category edit panel, giving no output because it was deactivated.

Reactivating the extension or setting

```
<active>false</active>
```

in its module file under app/etc/modules solves the problem.